# Shorter way to write variables as input/ output of function

Tags: python-2.7

I`m using a function within a script which produces a number of variables.
The function is used at different places in the script.
It produces variables a,b,c,d,e etc

```
def function(input):
    a,b,c,d,e = 1,2,3,4,5
    return a,b,c,d,e
```

I call the function as follows:

```
a,b,c,d,e = function(input)
```

This way all the variables a,b,c,d,e etc... need to be repeated every time I want to use the function. Is there a way to prevent this repetition?

For example I tried to make a list of the variables and then zip them with the output of the function and then connect them but that is not working.

```
listofvariables = [a,b,c,d,e]    

outputfunction = function(input)
gezipt = zip(listofvariables,outputfunction)
for itm in gezipt:
     itm[0] = itm[1]
```

That way when I change the function I would have to rewrite the list with the variables once and not every time the function is used. but that doesnt work.

Comment: I don't quite understand your code. The function doesn't return anything.

Comment: sorry, I forgot the return part of the function I added it to my post

Comment: And what was the problem again with writing `a, b, c, d, e = function(input)`? Why do you think that is worse than writing those 4 lines of code that don't work?

Comment: I simplified the script for the question. In my script the function produces more than 25 variables. And it  is used about 10 times on different places in the script. When I change the output of the function I have to change the variables repetativly 10 times. I`m just curious if there is a way to prevent this repetition.

Comment: Probably returning 25 values isn't a good design to begin with. You can also just assign all values to a single variable, which will be a tuple: `thevalues = function(input)`. Then if you need to access the `i`'th value (counting from 0) you can use `thevalues[i]`.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Why do you think that it is not a good design when a function returns 25 values?

Comment: For example, because it becomes difficult to assign them to variables, as you have discovered.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question, of whether you can programmatically set variables is mostly no. There probably *are* ways you could make it work, but they'd be fragile or hard to understand. Generally speaking, treating variable names as part of your program's data is a bad idea.

If you have lots of related data items, you should generally be using a data structure to group them all together, rather than using separate variables for each one. Your example is dealing with a batch of five variables, and at several different points keeps them in a tuple. That tuple is probably what you want, though you could use a list if you need to modify the values, or maybe a dictionary if you wanted to be able to index them by key (e.g. `{"a": 1, "b": 2}`). For other more complicated situations, you might need to program up your own container for the data, such as a class. You might even use several different containers for different sub-sets of your data, and then keep those separate containers in a further container (resulting in a nested data structure).

Unfortunately, that's about as detailed as we can get without more details about your circumstances. If you need more specific help, you should probably ask another question with more details about your actual application.

Comment: Thanks! I think I found a solution